# How to count characters of a subtree in emacs org mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would like to count characters in a subtree (heading) in org mode. Right now I have figured out how to count characters in a single paragraph, but not over multiple paragraphs. I first define a source block:

```
#+NAME: countChars
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :var X="" :results output
echo "$X" | wc --chars
#+END_SRC
```

And then I use it on named paragraphs:

```
#+NAME: paragraph
This is the paragraph

#+CALL: countChars(paragraph)
```

This works well but the #+NAME: only covers one paragraph. I have tried to use a heading as argument but I could not make it work.

EDIT: Based on comments, I came up with:

```
#+NAME: countChars
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results output :eval no-export :exports results
(interactive)
(save-excursion
  (org-mark-subtree)
  (setq a (- (mark) (point)))
  (deactivate-mark)
  (prin1 'Count= )
  (prin1 a))
#+END_SRC
```

which does almost what I want when invoked as

```
#+CALL: countChars()
```

but has the problem of counting source code blocks (including itself) as well as text. I would like to count text only (excluding the headline).

Comment: Put `(forward-line 1)` after `(org-mark-subtree)`. Also, you can leave out `(interactive)`. That's just for turning defuns into M-x commands. Also, I don't know what you want to happen if the subtree content contains other subtrees.

Comment: Great! I need to count at the deepest subtree level only, so I am not worried about further subtrees. I am trying, however, to include the character count when exporting. I can reduce everything to a single call_* line, but this is counted by the function. I am assuming there is a command like forward-line that would allow skipping the last line of text in the subtree?

Comment: I've updated my answer to skip the last line as requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use `#+NAME` in front of a source block, not a subtree.

It's easier to write this in emacs lisp.

This code block will count the number of characters in the current subtree, not including the header or the last line of the content:
If you want to count the number of characters in the current subtree using emacs lisp, try this:

```
(save-excursion
  (org-mark-subtree) ;mark the whole subtre
  (forward-line 1)   ;move past header
  (exchange-point-and-mark) ;swap point and mark (ends of region)
  (forward-line -1)  ;move backwards past the last line
  (let ((nchars (- (point) (mark))))
    (deactivate-mark) ;clear the region
    (message "%d" nchars))))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works very well! Now, my elisp is really close to 0. Would it be hard to modify such that the function prints in the buffer rather than displaying in the minibuffer? Like my source block in the question did...